# iText generates different pdfs with the same code

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm trying to write a unit test for my pdf generation code with iText. But I found the files generated by iText are slightly different in binary. I guess it's due to the metadata(e.g. creation time).

I wonder if my guess is correct. Also how to manually set the metadata. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your guess is only partially correct. Some data structures in memory are non-deterministic, but it is easier to give you an answer if you just post an example of such a binary difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the creation time to the metadata of the PDF, there will be a difference between two PDF's created with the same code at different moments in time because the creation time will be different. That's one reason why the PDF's are different.

Metadata is optional, so you could choose to omit all metadata (which is hard to do with iText, because iText *always* adds metadata). However, even in that case there will be differences.

One difference is mandatory since PDF 2.0. Already in earlier versions of the PDF specification, the concept of a unique ID for each PDF was introduced. This unique ID consists of an array of two values that are identical when a PDF is created from scratch. If a PDF is manipulated, the first value of the ID remains permanent, whereas the second part changes. Before PDF 2.0, this ID pair was optional, though many PDF creators will add it. Starting with PDF 2.0, such an ID pair is mandatory, and no two different PDF's should be created using the same ID. In practice, the values of such an ID pair are created by creating a message digest of different parameters, usually including the current time to make sure the ID is different for two PDF's created at a different time.

Timestamps are also used e.g. when you create a digital signature. Another difference might depend on the technology or programming language you are using to create the PDF. For instance: during the creating of the PDF some hash set is populated with a list of objects. These objects are then written to a PDF file in an order that might be different depending because order doesn't matter in a hash set. The order in which you receive the objects from a hash set depends on many things, and is usually hard to predict (see the difference between an `ArrayList`, `TreeSet` and `HashSet` in Java).

For instance: if you have an unordered list with objects "apple", "pear", "banana", and you write this unordered list to a file, there are 6 different orders in which these objects can appear in the file:

1. apple, pear, banana
2. apple, banana, pear
3. pear, apple, banana
4. pear, banana, apple
5. banana, apple, pear
6. banana, pear, apple

Suppose that these objects weren't fruit, but objects in a PDF, then any of the 6 different orders would result in valid PDF syntax.

Comment: There actually can be other time stamps in addition to those in the metadata, e.g. in case of signed PDFs or PDFs with file attachments...